# How to call the REST API once the email verification completes with azure b2c SignUporSignIn flow using custom policies?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm new to Azure B2C custom policies, I just want to know how to call the REST API once the email verification completes with azure b2c SignUporSignIn flow using custom policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [Display Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-controls), there are two places this can be achieved:

1. Add an extra [Validation Claims Exchange Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-controls#display-control-actions) after `AadSspr-VerifyCode` to call your REST API technical profile
2. On your `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` technical profile, add a [Validation Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles#validationtechnicalprofile) after the `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail` validation technical profile to call your REST API technical profile.
3. Add another orchestration step after the Sign Up orchestration step which only executes if the `newUser` claim is set to true.

If you're not using display controls, only point 2, and 3 will be available to you.

Display claims sample (point 1):

```xml
<DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
  ...
  <Actions>
    <Action Id="SendCode">
      <ValidationClaimsExchange>
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AadSspr-SendCode" />
      </ValidationClaimsExchange>
    </Action>
    <Action Id="VerifyCode">
      <ValidationClaimsExchange>
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AadSspr-VerifyCode" />
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-OnEmailVerified" />
      </ValidationClaimsExchange>
    </Action>
  </Actions>
</DisplayControl>
```

Local account sign up validation technical profile (point 2):

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
  <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
  ...
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-OnEmailVerified" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Orchestration step sample (point 3):

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>newUser</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>newUser</Value>
      <Value>True</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
     <ClaimsExchange Id="OnNewUserCreated" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-OnEmailVerified" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Thank you, l'm not using display control, if I use ValidationTechnicalProfile  under LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail technical profile it will trigger only while submitting the form. I'm looking for something where once the email address is verified, I need to trigger the REST API which will get the First name and last name from the database for the user based on email address and prepopulate the First Name and Last name fields based on the response from the REST API.

Comment: The only options in this case would be to split the email verification screen from the other user data collection screen. Even if you were using display controls I don't believe they will be able to hydrate already rendered controls. You can find the sample for splitting email verification and account creation on the [Azure-Ad-B2C Samples repo: split email verification and signup](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup)

Comment: Thank you @bolt-io, I tried this approach before posting the question, but we are looking to do it without splitting the email verification step, but as you said I believe it's not possible.